# After installing redis-commander on Ubuntu subsystem on windows how to enable it?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Have installed Ubuntu subsystem in windows and using Redis with nodejs App. 
Redis-commander is installed successfully but not be able to enable it so I can start viewing database on browser with GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1. Open Ubuntu Command terminal

Step 2. Write command there `redis-server`

Step 3. Open Window Terminal and write command `redis-commander`

> I assume that you have installed redis-commander global

Step 4. Open `localhost:8081`